# Armazenar Time no banco de dados

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, time

Estou tendo problemas preciso armazenar o valor de dois valores de hora e minutos no banco de dados.

Eis o `input` e o `jQuery`

```html
<input type="time" name="txthoraentrada" id="txthoraentrada"class="form-control" required>
```

```js
var hrentrd = $('#txthoraentrada').val();
```

Observações:

- Tentei usar `val('HH:mm')`, mas não salva os valores no banco e exibe um *warning* falando que está fora do padrão, mesmo este sendo uns dos padrões que o próprio *warning* fala é valido.
- Tentei usar o plugin do `timepicker`. Não deu certo :(
- Estou usando `jQuery`, `AJAX` e `PHP`.
- O campo é do tipo `time` no banco de dados
- Está gravando `00:00:00` no banco.
  Agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Answer (score -2):

Boa noite Diego_F.

Não ficou bem claro. O jQuery consegue enviar a informação para o backend?
Se sim, e o problema for gravar na base de dados, então tente salvar seu dado em formato string, pois o campo **'TIME'** aceita tipo numérico e tipo string.

***Ex.: 'HH:MM:SS'***

Comment: Quando uso val('HH:mm:ss') não envia. E quando uso somente val() salva como 00:00:00 independente do valor que eu coloque.

Comment: Resolvi o problema, era meu arquivo php que estava incorreto.

Comment: @Diego_F envie a sua solução como resposta e depois a aceite como resposta correta para que caso alguém mais tenha esse problema saiba resolver e a questão possa ser fechada no fórum.

Answer (score -6):

Um campo time no banco de dados salva nesse formato: 00:00:00 e o campo input time esta enviando os dados nessa forma 00:00, se alterar o tipo de campo no banco de dados para varchar provavelmente vai salvar